# Tensors without explicit specifications in xCoba

Tags: xact

In the standard Schwarzschild setup I have the following tensor:

```
HH = CTensor[{{99*\[Theta][]^4, 4*r[]^3, BB[r[]], CC[r[]]}, {-AA[r[]],
     0, DD[r[]], 4*r[]^3*EE[r[]]}, {-BB[r[]], -DD[r[]], \[Theta][]^3, 
    GG[r[]]}, {-CC[r[]]*4*r[]^3, -EE[r[]], -GG[r[]], 
    0}}, {-chartMM, -chartMM}]
```

But when I take the Lie derivative of it I do not get AA'(r) type terms.  It does do the derivatives of the explicit, e.g., r[]^4 type terms giving 4r[]^3.  In other words, it is treating AA(r) as a constant AA.  How do I get it to recognize that AA is a function of r?

Comment: You should define AA as a scalar function, using DefScalarFunction[AA]. When asking questions or reporting issues about xAct, it is important that full code is included, in particular with all DefXXX commands.